# Jquery if checkbox or multiple checkboxes are checked change a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, checkbox, selection

So I have this here, this is supposed to count the words and display the "price", and the price should be determined by whether 1 or both check-boxes are checked. So e.g if user checked `NTV` then I want `x = 4`, if he checked `STS` then I want `x = 2`, if both then for it to display the price that is determined `(x * 2) + (x * 4)`.

I also cant seem to get the input box to work with Cyrillic input, sorry if something doesn't make sense I'm not a native English speaker

```
<input type='checkbox' value='ntv' name='v'> STS<br/>
<input type='checkbox' value='sts' name='v'> NTV<br/>
<input class="input1" style="width:350px;" type="text" lang="ru-RU" name="Text_send" id="Text">
<input id="finalcount" value="0" disabled />
```

```js
$(function() {
    var wordCounts = {};
    $("input[type='text']:not(:disabled)").keyup(function() {
        var matches = this.value.match(/\b/g);
        wordCounts[this.id] = matches ? matches.length / 2 : 0;
        var finalCount = 0;
        var x = ;

        $.each(wordCounts, function(k, v) {
            finalCount += v*x;
        });
        $('#finalcount').val(finalCount)
    }).keyup();
});
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a value assignment: `var x = ;`. That will be generating a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CDLtn/2/)

**HTML**

```
<input type='checkbox' value='2' name='v'>STS
<input type='checkbox' value='4' name='v'>NTV
```

**js**

```
$(function () {
    var wordCounts = {};
    $("input[type='text']:not(:disabled)").keyup(function () {
        var matches = this.value.match(/\b/g);
        wordCounts[this.id] = matches ? matches.length / 2 : 0;
        var finalCount = 0;
        var x = 0;
        $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            x += parseInt(this.value);
        });
        x = (x == 0) ? 1 : x;
        $.each(wordCounts, function (k, v) {
            finalCount += v * x;
        });
        $('#finalcount').val(finalCount)
    }).keyup();
    $('input:checkbox').change(function () {
        $('input[type="text"]:not(:disabled)').trigger('keyup');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Tushar, that works just I needed it to, any thoughts on cyrillic/russian input?

Comment: @user2735624 no can't understand that . if you are satisfied you can accept the answer http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png